# Recursive virtual call not working as it should?

Tags: c++, recursion

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Flower
{
    virtual string str() = 0;
};

struct Rose : Flower
{
    string str() override { return "A rose"; }
};

struct RedFlower : Flower
{
    Flower& flower;
    RedFlower(Flower& flower) : flower{ flower } {}
    string str() override { return flower.str() + " that is red"; }
};

int main()
{
    Rose rose;
    RedFlower red_rose{ rose };
    RedFlower red_red_rose{ red_rose };
    RedFlower red_red_red_rose{ red_red_rose };
    cout << rose.str() << endl;
    cout << red_rose.str() << endl;
    cout << red_red_rose.str() << endl;
    cout << red_red_red_rose.str() << endl;
}
```

It prints out

```
A rose
A rose that is red
A rose that is red
A rose that is red
```

Shouldn't it print out

```
A rose
A rose that is red
A rose that is red that is red
A rose that is red that is red that is red
```

??? Why is it not printing out what it should? Does the compiler optimise away the calls or is the class hierarchy lost along the away? I don't seem to pin point what exactly it is that I'm missing. I know something must be wrong with my code. I believe dynamic polymorphism is lost somewhere in the call stack... ?

Comment: Hint: Your constructor is not actually called. Do you know about copy constructors?

Comment: In the meantime I'm voting to reopen, because it's not that obvoious what is happening here and for a beginner even a debugger will not help all that much. But I guess it's easier to just tell people to solve their propblems themselves than just answering or at least leving some comment...

Comment: yeah... I can't answer my own question, so I'm going answer it here. I forgot I was using references, which means I actually got just two objects: the first two, a Rose and a RedRose. The other RedRoses were just referencing the second RedRose. BTW, I know how use a debugger and I already tried it before asking the question.....

Comment: It's been reopened, so you can answer the question now :)

Comment: I'm learning the Decorator design pattern. I know about copy constructors. Thanks for the  upvote.

Comment: @cigien Thanks :)

Comment: @churill Turns out I don't know about copy constructors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem here is, that the compiler automatically generates a copy- constructor with the following signature:

```
RedFlower(RedFlower const &)
```

That constructor is being called instead of your custom one. One solution is to add an explicit cast to `Flower &`:

```
Rose rose;
RedFlower red_rose{ rose };
RedFlower red_red_rose{ static_cast<Flower &>(red_rose) };
RedFlower red_red_red_rose{ static_cast<Flower&>(red_red_rose) };
```

Comment: I wonder what happens if you make the copy constructor `explicit`?